# convert date timeline in rows to columnar format in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

My data is like :

```
SKU      StartDateTime  EndDateTime
es311335    6/30/2013   5/24/2015
es311355    6/30/2013   6/28/2015
es311470    6/30/2013   12/14/2014
es311478    6/30/2013   6/28/2015
es311501    6/30/2013   6/28/2015
es311574    6/30/2013   6/28/2015
es311632    6/30/2013   6/22/2014
```

I want it to be in format:

```
SKU         Date
es311335    6/30/2013
es311335    7/7/2013
es311335    7/14/2013
es311335    7/21/2013
es311335    7/28/2013
es311335    8/4/2013
------      ------
es311335    24/05/2014
```

I have used the below query but this is not giving me the correct result.

```
DECLARE @Interval NVARCHAR(10), @I DATETIME, 
@IntervalMin DATETIME, @IntervalMax DATETIME

--- Set Interval DAY or MONTH or YEAR -----------------

SET @Interval = 'DAY' 

-------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Records TABLE
(StartDateTime DATETIME
 ,EndDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Records
SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime
From records

DECLARE @Results TABLE
(StartDate DATETIME
 ,EndDate DATETIME)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Records)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @IntervalMin = startdatetime, @IntervalMax = enddatetime
  FROM @Records

  SET @I = @IntervalMin

  WHILE (@I <= @IntervalMax)
  BEGIN
    IF @Interval = 'DAY'
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @Results
      SELECT @I, CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 7, @I)) > @IntervalMax 
          THEN @IntervalMax ELSE CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 7, @I)) END

      SET @I = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 7, @I))
    END
END

  DELETE FROM @Records 
  WHERE startdatetime = @IntervalMin 
  AND enddatetime = @IntervalMax
END

SELECT *
FROM @Results
```

Comment: You need to start thinking in sets. This should be done with a tally table instead a loop. Here is an article that talks in depth about what a tally table is. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in my comment that you should use a tally table. Here is my version of a tally table. I keep this as a view in my system so I don't have to store it permanently and it generates 10,000 rows with zero reads.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now how does this apply to what you are trying to do? We can some date math to incorporate the tally table into a solution that is set based instead of an RBAR (row by agonizing row) looping construct. Before we can get to the solution we have to build the data in a format that is consumable by others.

Here is one way to do that.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    SKU char(9)
    , StartDateTime datetime
    , EndDateTime datetime
)

insert #Something
select 'es311335', '6/30/2013', '5/24/2015' union all
select 'es311355', '6/30/2013', '6/28/2015' union all
select 'es311470', '6/30/2013', '12/14/2014' union all
select 'es311478', '6/30/2013', '6/28/2015' union all
select 'es311501', '6/30/2013', '6/28/2015' union all
select 'es311574', '6/30/2013', '6/28/2015' union all
select 'es311632', '6/30/2013', '6/22/2014'
```

OK cool. Now we have a tally table AND some data to work with. Let's see how simple this can be when we use our tally table.

```
select s.*
    , DATEADD(week, N - 1, StartDateTime)
from #Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(week, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) + 1
order by SKU, DATEADD(week, N - 1, StartDateTime)
```